# количество кнопок клавиатуры в строке в клавиатуре под сообщением telebot python telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

есть код написаный на python с библиотекой telebot и есть такой код для инлайновой клавиатуры

```
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("BCH", callback_data='BCH')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("BTC", callback_data='BTC')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ETC", callback_data='ETH')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("LTC", callback_data='LTC')
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("DOGE", callback_data='DOGE')
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ОПЛАТА ЧАСТЯМИ", callback_data='part_pay', url="https://telegra.ph/OPLATA-CHASTYAMI-12-03")
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ГАРАНТ", callback_data='grnt', url="https://example.com")
            item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ТЕСТ ПРОГРАММЫ", callback_data='test_program')
            item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ", callback_data='pay_info', url="https://example.com")

            markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9 )
```

код выдает вот такую клавиатуру под сообщением[image: клавиатура]

а хочу чтобы выводил вот такую клавиатуру

[image: желаемая клавиатура]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

coins = [
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("BCH", callback_data="BCH"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("BTC", callback_data="BTC"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("ETC", callback_data="ETC"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("LTC", callback_data="LTC"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("DOGE", callback_data="DOGE")
]

payment = [
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("ОПЛАТА ЧАСТЯМИ", callback_data='part_pay', url="https://telegra.ph/OPLATA-CHASTYAMI-12-03"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton("ГАРАНТ", callback_data='grnt', url="https://example.com")
]

test = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ТЕСТ ПРОГРАММЫ", callback_data='test_program')

consult = types.InlineKeyboardButton("КОНСУЛЬТАЦИЯ", callback_data='pay_info', url="https://example.com")

markup.add(*coins)
markup.add(*payment)
markup.add(test)
markup.add(consult)
```